# USING DrawerNavigator AND BottomTabNavigator HOW TO PUT DrawerIcon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

Im using my main menu with DrawerNavigator.
Inside a screen i use BottomTabNavigator.

I put the DrawerIcon of each screen like this:

```
....
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
...

static navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="home" style={{ fontSize: 24, color: tintColor }} />
    )
  }

...

}
```

But, in the screen that i use the TabNavigator i dont export a class, y export createBottomNavigator, like so:

```
class MetasSemanaAnterior extends React.Component {...}

class MetasScreen extends React.Component {...}

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    MetasMain: MetasScreen,
    MetasAnterior: MetasSemanaAnterior,
});
```

I dont know where put my navigationOptions of the DrawerNavigator!

Help Please! TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved in this way:

in the main screen, where i create my Drawer Navigation, i set the DrawerIcon. So that, the icon appear despite i dont set it in the child Screens

set DrawerIcon where you create the DrawerMenu:

```
    const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
      ChatBot: {
        screen: HomeScreen
      },
      Profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen
      },
      METAS: {
        screen: MetasScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
//here i set the drawerIcon
          drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => { return (<Icon name="flag" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} />) }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this is what you are looking for but you could try this if i am understanding it correctly.
You could refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html for things to make sense.

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    MetasMain: MetasScreen,
    MetasAnterior: MetasSemanaAnterior,
});

tabNavigator.navigationOptions = () => {

}

export default tabNavigator;
```

Comment: That could works for export the TAB navigator options, but i also need to export the Drawer Navigation Options. Ty